# Python progress bar with dynamic length

Tags: python

I'm writing a web crawler that discovers links and processes the page information.

Since this can be a process with no end I don't know how many elements I have when building a progress bar, like 5 links completed / who knows when we're done.

But I do know how many links I've visited and how many links I've detected.

So number of links visited / detected links.

What i'd like to do is use an api like click or something else to make a progress bar.

Where the length of the bar can change, i.e. I can update the detected bar... Think a loading bar and the user is a 90% and suddenly drops to 10%. Aw bummer lol'

Looking at the click api there appears to be two ways to use their progress bar.

```
with click.progressbar(all_the_users_to_process) as bar:
for user in bar:
    modify_the_user(user)
```

or

```
with click.progressbar(length=total_size,
                   label='Unzipping archive') as bar:
for archive in zip_file:
    archive.extract()
    bar.update(archive.size)
```

[Progress Bar](http://click.pocoo.org/5/utils/#showing-progress-bars)

Can I make what I've described above using the click progress bar?

If I can't what do I need to make a progress bar where the completed value with change... 90% -> 10% -> 20%.

Thank you!

EDIT: more details

I have a list of objects, called LinkElements. These elements have a visited boolean.

I was thinking I could potentially update the iterator:

```
with click.progressbar(like_elements_list) as link_elements:
    for link in link_elements:
        ... do stuff with link ....
        link_elements.update(like_elements_list)
```

The idea doesn't seem to work though... or I'm not understanding it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported, but you can use click to provide the functionality that you're looking for.

```
import click

links_visited = 0
links_detected = 100

with click.progressbar(length=1000) as bar:
    for link in link_elements_list:

        # ... do stuff ...

        links_visited += 1
        links_detected += 0 # Increment how many more new links were found

        progress = float(links_visited) / float(links_detected)
        bar.pos = int(progress * 999) + 1
        bar.update(0)
```

You move the progress bar manually through `bar.pos` and then call upon `update(0)`. Since the `update()` method works by increments, you can pass in `0` just to do the rendering.

Now, I have to note a few things:

- `length=1000` I'm hardcoding a value of `1000` so we can provide a "percentage" between 0-1000.
- `bar.pos = int(progress * 999) + 1` Why the `+1`? Well, when you call `update()` it will attempt to calculate the average time, this means that with a `bar.pos` of `0`, you get a division by zero error. The `+1` is to avoid this situation.